# Why does this Function written in JS return true even if the condition is not satisfied?

Tags: javascript

I am just starting to learn Javascript and one of our first assignments were the classic check_if_palindrome function. I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

```js
function palindrome(str1) {
  console.log(str1.split('').reverse().join(''));
  console.log(str1);

  if (str1 == str1.split().reverse().join('')) {
    return (true)
  } else {
    return (false)
  }
}

if (palindrome('wow442421') == true) {
  console.log('YES')
} else {
  console.log('NOPE');
}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Your console output doesn’t match what you are actually doing. `.split('')` and `.split()` are different things.

Comment: My bad. I completely missed it. I was just learning about the split() function. Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `''` in the second `split()`. Do not repeat code, it is error prone, you should use a variable to hold the result and reuse it when necessary:

```js
function palindrome(str1) {
  const reversed = str1.split('').reverse().join('');
  console.log(str1, reversed);

  if (str1 === reversed){
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

if (palindrome('wow442421') === true) {
  console.log('YES')
} else{
  console.log('NOPE');
}
```

Also, since `str1 === str1.split('').reverse().join('')` already returns a boolean, simply return this value, the `if/else` statement is not necessary:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  return str.split('').reverse().join('') === str;
}

if (palindrome('wow442421')) {
  console.log('YES')
} else{
  console.log('NOPE');
}
```

And if you want to make it more succinct, you can do this:

```js
const isPalindrome = str => str === [...str].reverse().join('')

console.log(isPalindrome('wow44'));
console.log(isPalindrome('Roma amoR'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `split('')` instead of `split()`, `split()` will split at every space character, `split('')` splits at every character, which is what you want:

```js
function palindrome(str1) {
  if (str1 == str1.split('').reverse().join('')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

if (palindrome('wow442421') == true) {
  console.log('YES')
} else {
  console.log('NOPE');

}
```